# Silverstripe framework - Default Controller

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

is it possible to change the default Controller that silverstripes starts with? 
maybe it could work with routes? alternatively maybe a redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [SilverStripe's routing documentation](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/director).
You'll want to overwrite the default routing in [cms/_config/routes.yml](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/blob/master/_config/routes.yml#L8).
Not sure what you're trying to achieve though, maybe you're better served with `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: Thanks! I tried with routes. So now the application starts with the Controller that I want when calling e.g. just the domain of the application...
`Director:
  rules:
    '': 'My_Controller'`